# Sling ResourceResolverFactory inside @Activate throws RunTimeException

Tags: annotations, osgi, aem, activation

I am new to AEM OSGI , any help would be appreciated
I have a class which contains @Activate annotated activate method inside which i am resolving and building up resources

```
@Component
@Service(MyTest.class)
public class MyTest {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTest.class);
...
...
@Reference
private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;

@Activate
protected void activate() {
    final ResourceResolver resolver;
    try {
        resolver = resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        LOG.error("error resolving resource resolver", e);
        return;
    }
```

I have a servlet that invokes this class  and on the servlet i am using

```
@Reference
MyTest test;


@Override
protected void doPost
....
```

Here is the error i am getting

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke method 'activate' for class com.demo.MyTest
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke method 'activate' for class com.demo.MyTest at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.OsgiServiceUtil.invokeMethod(OsgiServiceUtil.java:263)
at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.OsgiServiceUtil.activateDeactivate(OsgiServiceUtil.java:101)
at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.MockOsgi.activate(MockOsgi.java:211)
at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.MockOsgi.activate(MockOsgi.java:222)
at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.context.OsgiContextImpl.registerInjectActivateService(OsgiContextImpl.java:155)
at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.context.OsgiContextImpl.registerInjectActivateService(OsgiContextImpl.java:142)
at com.Demo.MyDemoTest(MyDemoTest.java:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.Demo.MyTest.activate(MyTest.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.OsgiServiceUtil.invokeMethod(OsgiServiceUtil.java:254)
... 33 more
```

Please help me understand where i am making the mistake
Also if i move the resolver factory definition to a public method inside that same class its working perfectly

Comment: Please post the whole error message including stack trace.

Comment: Also, the title of your question says "throws `NullPointerException`" but the question text says the error is `RuntimeException`. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry fixed description now

Comment: It looks like this error is thrown during the build? Specifically during the testing phase of the maven build? Or is it thrown on AEM (in error.log) ??

Comment: The NPE is being thrown on line 75 of `MyTest.java`. You haven't line-numbered your source code, so can you highlight which line is number 75?

Comment: Error produced during test run..i was trying to run that single unit test from my IDE.

Comment: Line 75 is protected void activate()

Comment: Can you share the test class? Just throwing an idea here -> You'll have to mock the references you are using. If you are using any  junit rule like `OsgiContext`, try mocking `ResourceResolverFactory` using `osgiContext.registerService(ResourceResolverFactory.class, new MockResourceResolverFactory());`.

Comment: Line 75 cannot be `protected void activate()`. You cannot get an NPE on a method declaration. Check again. By the way it sounds very much like the `resolverFactory` field is null during the activate method because you are running this in a JUnit test and nothing is initializing that field.

Answer (score 3):

### Reason for the NullPointerException

Although not explicitly mentioned in the question the provided stacktrace reveals that the service is "run" within a unit test.

Furthermore, the stack trace reveals, that the `OsgiContext` is used, which does not provide an implementation of the `ResourceResolverFactory`.

Since no `ResourceResolverFactory` is registered within the mock OSGi context, the `@Reference` can not be injected upon service registration and activation. When the `ResourceResolverFactory` is then called in the activate method the reference is `null` and therefore the `NullPointerException`is thrown.

### Proposed Solution

Therefore, I would advise to use the excellent `AemContext` which is provided by the [wcm.io aem-mock framework](http://wcm.io/testing/aem-mock/) or at least the `SlingContext` provided by [sling-mocks](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-mock.html).

The unit test would look like this:

```
public class MyUnitTest {

    @Rule
    public AemContext context;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        MyTest service = context.registerInjectActivateService(new MyTest());

        [... additional test code ...]
    }
}
```

Since the `AemContext` already has a functional `ResourceResolverFactory` (mock) registered, the unit test code does not have to create a mock and register it. When the `registerInjectActivateService()` method is called a new instance of the `MyTest` class is instantiated and the referenced `ResourceResolverFactory` is injected.

### Additional Note

Please do not create *service-wide* `ResourceResolvers`. This is a bad practice. `ResourceResolver` should be short-lived. That means that they are only used for a few "operations" (like reading a resource) and then discarded.

The best way to do this is to use the `try-with-resource` statement like this:

```
public class MyTest {

    private static final SERVICE_NAME = "MyTestService";
    private static final Map<String, Object> authenticationInfo = Collections.singletonMap(ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, SERVICE_NAME);

    @Reference
    private ResourceResolverFactory resourceResolverFactory;

    public void someMethod() {

        try (ResourceResolver resolver = getResourceResolver()) {
            [... use resolver to do stuff in JCR ...]
        }

    }

    private ResourceResolver getResourceResolver() {
        try {
            return resourceResolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(authenticationInfo);
        } catch (LoginException cause) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to obtain ResourceResolver!", cause)
        }
    }
}
```

I chose to create a separate method to create the `ResourceResolver` to avoid cluttering `someMethod()` with exception handling. But that is obviously something that can be changed.

Since administrative `ResourceResolver` are deprecated I also chose to use a service `ResourceResolver`. To use those you need to create a service user mapping. You can find out more about this in the [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/security-service-users.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that creating the resolver inside of Acivate method is anti-pattern. Your service might be called by multiple threads in parallel, and  that these calls can be processed in parallel. 
When we do write or read a resource then JCR session apply [internal lock](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/trunk/jackrabbit-core/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/session/SessionState.java), which prevents multiple sessions to work in parallel on the very same session.

The best way to avoid this issue is to create resolver inside a method which you override.

```
@Override
 performSomeOperation(){
          final ResourceResolver resolver;
try {
    resolver = resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
} catch (LoginException e) {
    LOG.error("error resolving resource resolver", e);
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: Your first two sentences don't make a lot of sense. A service cannot be invoked by any consumers until after the `activate` method has completed.

Comment: true, but if you create session in activate method then it is not the best practice.

Comment: Although @NeilBartlett is right it is still considered bad practice to create  a service-wide `ResourceResolver`. A `ResourceResolver` should be short-lived and only used for a few operations before it is "thrown" away. The best way to achieve this is to use the `try-with-resource` statement, run a few operations within the `try` block. After the `try` block is run the `ResourceResolver` will be discarded automatically (because of the `AutoClosable` implementation).